# Next week in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I'm using oracle dbms and I have in `Employe` table a column `Birthdate`. I want to write a query that shows the employees who has a birthday next week. 
Is this correct ?

```
select name 
from employe 
where  to_char(birthdate,'DD-MM')=to_char(next_day(sysdate,1)+7,'DD-MM');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution would be

```
SELECT name
FROM employe
WHERE to_char(birthdate
              /* "move" the birthdate to the current year
                 to get a reliable week number */
              + CAST((EXTRACT(year FROM current_date)
                      - EXTRACT(year FROM birthdate)) || '-0'
                     AS INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH),
              'IW')
    = to_char(current_date + 7, 'IW');
```

The `IW` format returns the ISO week containing the date, which is probably what you are looking for. If you start your week on Sunday, add one to both dates.

Comment: This is not reliable. For example 1st of January can be week 52, 53 or 1 depending on the year. '2000-01-01' is week 52 whereas '2018-01-01' is week 01. Try `select 
to_char(add_months(date '2000-11-25', 12*level), 'IW')
from dual
connect by level < 10` and you get week 47 and week 48 depending on the year. btw. format `WW` has the same problem.

Comment: True, thanks for the hint. I have tried to fix the query.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the correct usage of `next_day()`: that function returns the date of the the next instance of a **day**. For example, to find the date of next Friday:

```
select next_day(sysdate, 'FRIDAY') from dual;
```

To find employees whose birthday is seven days from now, you need to just tweak your query a bit:

```
select name 
from employe
where to_char(birthdate,'DD-MM') = to_char(sysdate+7,'DD-MM');
```

Comment: That answers "who has birthday a week from now" rather than "who has birthday next week", as the question said. But maybe that's what was desired...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I corrected the OP's original query but you guessed their actual requirement :)